# How do I convert a list with values of different lengths into a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

For example, how do I get from:

```
list1 = ['ko', 'aapl', 'hon', 'disca']
```

to:

```
dict1 = {'ko': {}, 'aapl': {}, 'hon': {}, 'disca': {}}
```

---

The method I've been able to find

```
dict(list1)
```

unfortunately does not work here and returns the following error:

```
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #1 has length 4; 2 is required
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: `dict.fromkeys(list1, {})`

Comment: That works well! Thanks.

Comment: Yes! Successfully fooled someone! (Or several?)

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand?

Comment: elegant solution. fooled me -))

Comment: Wait, isn't it correct?

Comment: Oh... subtle...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following dictionary iteration:

```
dict1 = {i:{} for i in list1}
```

if you don't like the dictionary interation syntax, here it is in a plain loop:

```
dict1={}
for i in list1:
    dict1[i] = {}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dict(zip(list1,[{} for i in range(len(list1))]))
```